# How to handle print and sign event notifications from docusign api?

Tags: docusignapi

We have event notifications set up to send us a notification request for user actions.

I am trying to validate the document status to figure out if an user has signed a document. When the user has signed the document using docusign, I can capture the status from TabStatuses in the request.

However, I am not unable to figure out a way to handle the scenario where an user has opted to print and sign as the response for Print and Sign notifications does not include the `TabStatuses` with the status.

I have tried to go through the documentation to figure out if there is a way to confirm that the user has opted to print and sign the document, but I couldn't find what I was looking for. I do get `DocumentStatus` which returns a name node `signed_on_paper_<reference_id>` but it doesn't seem like the best approach to validate that the user has opted to print and sign.

Also in the case of multiple signers, what would be the best way to identify the status of each signer.

Sample response I received when a user opted to print and sign:

```
    <EnvelopeStatus>
        <RecipientStatuses>
            <RecipientStatus>
                <Type>
                    Signer
                </Type>
                <Email>
                    sdasari@plxs.com.au
                </Email>
                <UserName>
                    Shyam Dasari
                </UserName>
                <RoutingOrder>
                    1
                </RoutingOrder>
                <Sent>
                    2019-10-15T16:23:38.06
                </Sent>
                <Delivered>
                    2019-10-15T16:23:50.15
                </Delivered>
                <Signed>
                    2019-10-15T16:24:35.167
                </Signed>
                <DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" />
                <Status>
                    Completed
                </Status>
                <RecipientIPAddress>
                    115.70.163.1
                </RecipientIPAddress>
                <ClientUserId>
                    7422
                </ClientUserId>
                <CustomFields />
                <AccountStatus>
                    Active
                </AccountStatus>
                <EsignAgreementInformation>
                    <AccountEsignId>
                        e17f1e7a-2d2f-49e7-bdc6-gibberish
                    </AccountEsignId>
                    <UserEsignId>
                        75eda468-405c-48a3-bf8c-gibberish
                    </UserEsignId>
                    <AgreementDate>
                        2019-10-15T16:23:50.15
                    </AgreementDate>
                </EsignAgreementInformation>
                <RecipientId>
                    e1e8e99a-b89f-4d5c-aa27-gibberish
                </RecipientId>
            </RecipientStatus>
        </RecipientStatuses>
        <TimeGenerated>
            2019-10-15T16:24:55.6107604
        </TimeGenerated>
        <EnvelopeID>
            530aa34b-1991-4bc6-b374-gibberish
        </EnvelopeID>
        <Subject>
            Shyam Dasari has sent you a document to review and sign
        </Subject>
        <UserName>
            Legal Gateway Sandbox
        </UserName>
        <Email>
            callum@testsoftware.com.au
        </Email>
        <Status>
            Completed
        </Status>
        <Created>
            2019-10-15T16:23:37.67
        </Created>
        <Sent>
            2019-10-15T16:23:38.093
        </Sent>
        <Delivered>
            2019-10-15T16:23:50.307
        </Delivered>
        <Signed>
            2019-10-15T16:24:35.167
        </Signed>
        <Completed>
            2019-10-15T16:24:35.167
        </Completed>
        <ACStatus>
            Original
        </ACStatus>
        <ACStatusDate>
            2019-10-15T16:23:37.67
        </ACStatusDate>
        <ACHolder>
            Legal Gateway Sandbox
        </ACHolder>
        <ACHolderEmail>
            callum@test.com.au
        </ACHolderEmail>
        <ACHolderLocation>
            DocuSign
        </ACHolderLocation>
        <SigningLocation>
            Online
        </SigningLocation>
        <SenderIPAddress>
            115.70.163.1
        </SenderIPAddress>
        <EnvelopePDFHash />
        <CustomFields>
            <CustomField>
                <Name>
                    AccountId
                </Name>
                <Show>
                    false
                </Show>
                <Required>
                    false
                </Required>
                <Value>
                    12345
                </Value>
                <CustomFieldType>
                    Text
                </CustomFieldType>
            </CustomField>
            <CustomField>
                <Name>
                    AccountName
                </Name>
                <Show>
                    false
                </Show>
                <Required>
                    false
                </Required>
                <Value>
                    Legal Gateway
                </Value>
                <CustomFieldType>
                    Text
                </CustomFieldType>
            </CustomField>
            <CustomField>
                <Name>
                    AccountSite
                </Name>
                <Show>
                    false
                </Show>
                <Required>
                    false
                </Required>
                <Value>
                    demo
                </Value>
                <CustomFieldType>
                    Text
                </CustomFieldType>
            </CustomField>
        </CustomFields>
        <AutoNavigation>
            true
        </AutoNavigation>
        <EnvelopeIdStamping>
            true
        </EnvelopeIdStamping>
        <AuthoritativeCopy>
            false
        </AuthoritativeCopy>
        <DocumentStatuses>
            <DocumentStatus>
                <ID>
                    4321
                </ID>
                <Name>
                    sid_0a_2s_rando_doc_2_1405
                </Name>
                <TemplateName />
                <Sequence>
                    1
                </Sequence>
                <DocumentFields>
                    <DocumentField>
                        <Name>
                            reference_id
                        </Name>
                        <Value>
                            gibberish:1iKFJ0:gibberish-Cw
                        </Value>
                    </DocumentField>
                </DocumentFields>
            </DocumentStatus>
            <DocumentStatus>
                <ID>
                    2
                </ID>
                <Name>
                    Signed-on-Paper_more-gibberish-aa27-bafd4d393c02
                </Name>
                <TemplateName />
                <Sequence>
                    2
                </Sequence>
            </DocumentStatus>
        </DocumentStatuses>
    </EnvelopeStatus>
```

If a user opted to sign using docusign's esignature, I get `TabStatuses` in the response which help me identify the current state of the document.

```
<TabStatuses>
    <TabStatus>
        <TabType>
            SignHere
        </TabType>
        <Status>
            Signed
        </Status>
        <XPosition>
            699
        </XPosition>
        <YPosition>
            754
        </YPosition>
        <TabLabel>
            Signature 1_SignHere_gibberish_id
        </TabLabel>
        <TabName />
        <DocumentID>
            2460
        </DocumentID>
        <PageNumber>
            1
        </PageNumber>
    </TabStatus>
</TabStatuses>
```

I am using the docusign api version 2.

Answer (score 0):

When a user signs on paper there are no tabs.
Moreover, there's no way for you to know what paper was actually signed.
When the envelope is complete, you'll find an additional document in it, which is the paper that was faxed into the system. That is the only information you get back from a user that signs on paper. 
(We strongly discourage use of paper, and if one uses it - there are certain limitations to what we can support).

Comment: I wanted to wait and see how others are handling this scenario. I will mark it as answered in a week or so if I get no other responses, if that's alright.